# JTextField next to JLabel

Tags: java, swing, authentication, layout-manager

I want to get the text "User Name :" left of the JTextField as if entering details in to a system.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Log in System");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("User Name");
    field.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));

    frame.setSize(500, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel);
```

Comment: OK, what is the question?

Comment: There are a number of problems and frailties in the code snippet above. To begin with, why not use a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(..)` instead of a `JFrame`? E.G. `String userName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(parent, "User Name");`

Comment: You have to add label and field to the panel (using `add(Component)` method in `JPanel`). And you have to use a layout manager (`FlowLayout`, `GridLayout` etc.) to place the components (label and field) on the panel as you intend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout` for this.

```
JPanel container = new JPanel(new FlowLayout()); //panel
JTextField field = new JTextField();
JLabel label = new JLabel("User Name");

container.add(label); //add the label and text field
container.add(field);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, container, "Title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
//show it in a dialog
```

Comment: Something like `new JTextField(8);` would be better. The constructor will interpret the integer to mean the number of characters of text the field is expected to be able to display, then base its size on the that, combined with the current font.